# Function for thresholds of two variables

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a function with two variables. `m` has four categories: `equal to 19 or less`,`20`,`21`, and `22`. `al` has three categories: `less than 30`,`30 to 400`, and `over 400`.

```
Input:
m=c(19,20,21,22)
al=c(30,400)

Output:
out1 <- c(0.95, 0.94. 0.93, 0.92)
out21 <- 1.091+3.02*(al-30)
out22 <- 1.093+3.03*(al-30)
out23<-  1.099+3.08*(al-30)
out24 <- 1

out3 <- c(0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.93)
```

I am trying to write a function with `if` `else` that looks like

```
out <- function(m,al)
{ 
if(m<=19 & al<30){
  out=0.95     
} else {
  if(m=20 & al<30){
    out=0.94    
  } else {
    if(m=21 & al<30){
      out=0.93    
...
```

I like to get an easy looking function that gives me output more easily. Further explanation on the conditions:

```
If m <=19 & al <30, out=0.95
If m =20 & al <30, out=0.94

...

If m <=19 & al in between 30 and 400, out=1.091+3.02*(al-30)
If m =20 & al in between 30 and 400, out=1.093+3.03*(al-30)
...

If m <=19 & al >400, out=0.87
If m =20 & al >400, out=0.89
```

Comment: Use `cut`. Maybe combined with `switch`.

Comment: Do an SO search on 'findInterval' and 'interaction'